# Why jQuery steps not changing the section

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-4, jquery-steps

I was trying to make a multi-step form using jQuery steps. I have tried taking some code from the actual documentation but don't know why their web page isn't showing the code snippets. I tried taking the code from one tutorial blog but it is not working as I have expected. The section is not changing I am new to jQuery and never used steps I am not getting where I am going wrong.

Code :

```
<form id="example-form" action="#" class="tab-wizard wizard-circle wizard clearfix">
    <h6>Account</h6>
        <section>
        <br/>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-4 col-sm-push-4">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="userName-2">User name </label>
                    <input id="userName-2" name="userName" type="text" value="Les" class="form-control ">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="password-2">Password</label>
                    <input id="password-2" name="password" value ="password" type="text" class=" form-control">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="confirm-2">Confirm Password</label>
                    <input id="confirm-2" name="confirm" type="text" value="password" class=" form-control">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>

    <h6>Profile</h6>
    <section>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-2"></div>
            <div class="col-sm-4">

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="name-2">First name</label>
                    <input id="name-2" name="name" type="text" class="form-control">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="surname-2">Last name</label>
                    <input id="surname-2" name="surname" type="text" class="form-control">

                </div>
                <div class="form-group">

                    <label for="email-2">Email</label>
                    <input id="email-2" name="email" type="text" class="form-control email">
                </div>

            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-4">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="address-2">Address</label>
                    <input id="address-2" name="address" type="text" class="form-control">

                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="age-2">Age</label>
                    <input id="age-2" name="age" type="text" class="form-control number">

                </div>

            </div>
        </div>
    </section>

    <h6>Warning</h6>
    <section>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-2"></div>
            <div class="col-sm-8">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label>This is the question that is being asked to the user?</label>
                    <div class="radio">
                        <label>
                            <input type="radio" name="optionsRadios" id="optionsRadios1" value="option1">
                            Option one is this and that&mdash;be sure to include why it's great
                        </label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="radio">
                        <label>
                            <input type="radio" name="optionsRadios" id="optionsRadios2" value="option2" >
                            Option two can be something else and selecting it will deselect option one
                        </label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="radio">
                        <label>
                            <input type="radio" name="optionsRadios" id="optionsRadios3" value="option3" >
                            Option three. This is just a demo.
                        </label>
                    </div>
                </div></div>
        </div>
        <hr>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-2"></div>
            <div class="col-sm-4">

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="name-2">First name</label>
                    <input id="name-2" name="name" type="text" class="form-control">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="surname-2">Last name</label>
                    <input id="surname-2" name="surname" type="text" class="form-control">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-4">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="age-2">Age</label>
                    <input id="age-2" name="age" type="text" class="form-control number">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="email-2">Email</label>
                    <input id="email-2" name="email" type="text" class="form-control email">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
    <h6>Finish</h6>
    <section>

        <input id="acceptTerms-2" name="acceptTerms" type="checkbox" class=""> <label for="acceptTerms-2">I agree with the Terms and Conditions.</label>
    </section>
</form>
```

Js code:

```
 var form = $("#example-form");

    form.steps({
        headerTag: "h6",
        bodyTag: "section",
        transitionEffect: "fade",
        titleTemplate: '<span class="step">#index#</span> #title#'
    });
```

Apologies for the long code here, I tried making codesandbox of the example but I can't able to find the CDN for steps.css and also the CDN for steps.js was not working there.

Comment: And what exactly is the issue? I added the steps cdn and it seems to be working just fine.

Comment: @Esszed for me sections are not changing. When I click on next I expect it to change my section and land me over to next section but here only the first section is showing in all other links !!